# Declaring multiple aliases in an advanced PowerShell function

Tags: powershell, syntax, alias

The [documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15994.powershell-advanced-function-parameter-attributes.aspx) for declaring aliases in PowerShell cmdlets shows the following:

```
Function Get-SomeValue {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=0)]
        [Alias("MachineName")]
        [string[]]$ComputerName
    )

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
}
```

What syntax do I use to create multiple aliases?

- `[Alias("one","two","three)]`
- `[Alias("one")][Alias("two")][Alias("three")]`
- None of the above
- Something else?

P.S. When using `Get-Help`, where are the aliases supposed to be shown?  So far I don't see them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[Alias("one")][Alias("two")]` and `[Alias("one", "two")]` both work. You see the aliases when you display the help for the parameter:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help Get-SomeValue -Parameter computername

-ComputerName <string[]>

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    0
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
    Parameter set name           (All)
    Aliases                      one, two
    Dynamic?                     false
```

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51071896/45375):

If the documentation falls short, you can examine the underlying attribute class yourself, assuming some familiarity with C#:

`[Alias(...)]` implies class `AliasAttribute` in the `System.Management.Automation` namespace, i.e., `System.Management.Automation.AutomationAttribute`.

If you look up that class at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api, you'll find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.aliasattribute?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0, whose constructor has the following signature:

> `public AliasAttribute (params string[] aliasNames);`

This tells you that *multiple* alias names can be passed to `[Alias(...)]` as individual arguments.